# Flutter Charts: display value above each point

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, flutter, charts

I'm using the flutter_charts package and I want to display a text above each point containing its value.

Current:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

Comment: I tried to explore options in the `flutter_chart` For now, I have not found any configurations which allows placing the labels directly above the chart point. I think this is not yet implemented in the library itself since none of their examples displays this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was using another package called fl_chart: https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how to achieve this using fl_chart, mind helping out?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the solution for this problem. As mentioned in the previous answer, it does not give clear idea.

So here is what you need to do.
We are using the fl_charts and here is the example where they have almost implemented the same thing. https://github.com/imaNNeo/fl_chart/blob/master/example/lib/presentation/samples/line/line_chart_sample5.dart

So the catch is as you know when you touch the graph screen, you can see the value but in order to show it permanently look at this code and you will get a very nice idea how to make it stay there for all values.

Once you are able to make it stay you can fix the UI according to you. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

For those of us using fl_chart, this issue is discussed in the fl_chart git issues section [here](https://github.com/imaNNeo/fl_chart/issues/1322).

The gist of the answer is that you can use the **showingToolTipIndicators** property to persistently show certain tooltip indicators. You can find a working sample of this [here](https://github.com/imaNNeo/fl_chart/blob/master/example/lib/presentation/samples/line/line_chart_sample5.dart).

For the working sample, the magic code you really need is the something like the following, which shows tooltips permanently above the yourLineChartBarData line in spots 1 through 7

```
showingTooltipIndicators: showingTooltipOnSpots.map((index) {
   return ShowingTooltipIndicators([
     LineBarSpot(
       yourLineChartBarData,
       [1,2,3,4,6,7].indexOf(yourLineChartBarData),
       yourLineChartBarData.spots[index],
     ),
   ]);
 }).toList(),
```